# Nightmare.js wait() on javascript variables

Tags: javascript, wait, nightmare

How to use nightmare.js wait() to check if a javascript object/variable is loaded?

I am testing a webpage which heavily relies on javascript to render content. I am using Nightmare.js and I need to wait for the javascript to be loaded before I inject data and run my tests.
However, I have not found a way to use nightmare.js wait() to work with javascript.

I have tried something like this:

```
nightmare
.goto('file:\\\\' + __dirname + '\\index.html');
.wait("#ext-quicktips-tip") //make sure index.html is loaded
.wait(function() {
    return App.app //should return true when App.app is available
  }
.end()
.then();
```

I have tried using the debug console, and the page loads fine. App.app is available in the console, but nightmare.js will never see App.app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the [API documentation for Nightmare.js](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#waitfn-arg1-arg2), if you pass a function to the `wait` method, it should return `true` to tell Nightmare.js that it can resume the test.

So if you want the test to wait until `App.app` is available, you could have your function return a boolean expression that tests if it exists, i.e. is not `undefined`, like so:

```
nightmare
.goto('file:\\\\' + __dirname + '\\index.html');
.wait("#ext-quicktips-tip") //make sure index.html is loaded
.wait(function() {
    // return true when App.app is available
    return typeof App.app !== undefined;
}
.end();
```

Note that I left out the last `then` from your original code snippet – it is superfluous.